# How to clone conditional formatting to another column?

Tags: libreoffice, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I want to highlight values that are in the bottom 5th percentile in each column, for about 60 columns.  I set this conditional formatting for the first column, but I see no way to apply this to every column without manually doing it 60 times.  If I try copying the formatting, then the program will highlight the bottom 5th percentile for the whole dataset, rather than in each column.  Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead of [Condition - Cell value is - is in top N percent](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/05120100.html?&DbPAR=CALC) use [Condition - Formula is](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/05120200.html?&DbPAR=CALC) with a formula like

`B2>=LARGE(B$2:B$70;5)`

where `B2` is the first, upper left cell of the range

Pay attention to the address of the column for calculation - line numbers are indicated as absolute, and column names as relative. Due to this, the calculation of the condition for each of the cells of the formatted range will be calculated based on the values of the corresponding column.

[image: Example]